# Why is method tracing not working?

Tags: android

I have a scenario where the Gallery scrolling is stuttering and its not apparent what the bottleneck code is by looking at the code so I wanted to run a trace for an Activity as follows - By putting `android.os.Debug.startMethodTracing("lsd_1");` in `onCreate()` and `android.os.Debug.stopMethodTracing();` in `onPause()` or `onStop()` but when I run the Activity lifecycle, I don't any trace file generated at the end.

Have I performed tracing incorrectly in any way?